# OpenAI API key not working in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot, openai-api

I am trying to create a chatbot in my react app, and I'm not able to generate an LLM powered response. I've been studying documentation and checking out tutorials but am unable to fix.

I tried setting up a function for my chatbot, calling the api key, importing openai, setting up the parameters for the gpt-3.5-turbo model including temperature. The catch (error) section has a `setResponse` of 'Error generating response' and that's all I get after user inputs a question.

```
try {
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        prompt: question,
        max_tokens: 100,
        n: 1,
        stop: '\n',
        temperature: 1.17,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
        }
});
```

Comment: Also, as a note: If you have a catch section that throws away all the useful details and just outputs *Error generating response*, why would you expect it to say anything else? You've discarded anything useful and just provided a say-nothing message instead.

Comment: Be aware that if you put the `fetch` call in your React client app, the API_KEY becomes public information to anyone who opens your app . This can actually get the key revoked, also resulting in the "no response" error.

Comment: What's the best way to hide the API key in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as @KenWhite suggested, fix the fundamentals. Use the `try...catch` statement properly as follows:

```
try {
  // Your code here
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

#### Problem

*Note: OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*

There are a few problems with the code you posted in your question. The solutions to these problems I provide below differ depending on whether you use OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3` or `v4`.

To check your OpenAI NodeJS SDK version, run the following command:

```
npm info openai version
```

##### Problem 1: Passing an invalid parameter to the API endpoint

You're trying to pass `headers` as a parameter to the API endpoint, which is not a valid parameter. Remove it.

##### Solution

You need to set the Bearer token as follows...

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

##### Problem 2: Using the wrong method name

You want to use the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api)). Use the proper method name.

##### Solution

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

- `openai.createCompletion` <-- Wrong ✘
- `openai.createChatCompletion` <-- Correct (works with the Chat Completions API) ✔

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

- `openai.completions.create` <-- Wrong ✘
- `openai.chat.completions.create` <-- Correct (works with the Chat Completions API) ✔

##### Problem 3: Using the `prompt` parameter

You want to use the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api)).

The [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) uses the `messages` parameter, while the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) uses the `prompt` parameter.

##### Solution

Use the `messages` parameter instead of the `prompt` parameter.

#### Final solution

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`, try this:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

try {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello world' }],
    max_tokens: 100,
    n: 1,
    stop: '\n',
    temperature: 1.17,
  });

  console.log(chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`, try this:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

try {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello world' }],
    max_tokens: 100,
    n: 1,
    stop: '\n',
    temperature: 1.17,
  });

  console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: I have 4.8.0 for openai version. What should I use instead of createCompletion or createChatCompletion?

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm editing my code now. As far as the content section, is the "hello world" just to see if this works? The end goal is to create a functional chatbot that users can ask questions to.

Comment: Ok I tried your solution, I'm having issues with the dotenv setup. First time doing this. I'll need to solve that first to see if your solution is working.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting my application to work. the code you provided seems like it needs editing to fit into the project.

Comment: function Form() {
    const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');


    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello world' }],
            max_tokens: 100,
            n: 1,
            stop: '\n',
            temperature: 1.17,
            
     });

Comment: Am I using a function that is also outdated?

Comment: I am having the hardest time figuring this out. Now I'm getting this error, "A form field element should have an id or name attribute" even though I do have one. I'm also getting an error having to do with an image localhost/:1 Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image) The app loads finally, I was getting a white screen there for a bit before adjusting things. Just those two errors, but nothing happens now when i click the send message button. Also cant seem to hide api key.

Comment: Tried using git ignore and .env, also using dotenv-webpack

Comment: It seems there is an issue with   const env = getClientEnvironment();

Comment: I ended up going into the webpack.config.js file and changing things. Used copilot for suggestions, they may have been outdated.

Comment: @AndrewEscudero Huh, you have so many questions. I took a look at your GitHub repository, but after reading all your questions here, I see that you don't understand the code at all. As I already suggested in a DM, take a step back. Being ambitious is awesome. I definitely support this! But it has its own limits. You're trying to learn too many things too quickly. First, try to make a simple JavaScript file and call the OpenAI API. When this works, proceed with your development. Forget about React for now. Step by step. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will do!

Comment: I fixed all the errors with my react app, but I am taking a step back as you said and doing things piece by piece outside of react for now. Still learning about the backend section, but I have a working api key that is fine tuned. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AndrewEscudero You're welcome. :)